# Web2py PostgreSQL - Data not coming even though connection is successful

Tags: web2py, postgresql-9.3

This is my connection string :

```
DAL('postgres://postgres:000100010@localhost/postgres',pool_size=10,migrate=False,fake_migrate_all=True)
```

Pre Created Table

```
db.define_table('users',
                Field('first_name'),Field('last_name')
            )
```

Code for getting data

```
def users():
    rows = db(db.users).select()
    return dict(rows=rows)
```

Returns

```
{
    rows: [ ]
}
```

Comment: First, get rid of the fake_migrate_all argument -- if you needed that at all, it would only have been for a single request (to fix corrupted migration metadata). Second, have you confirmed via an external tool that you actually have records in the "users" table?

Comment: @Anthony yes. I have gui admin for postgresql. One other thing that I have this table in different schema. Can this be the reason for not getting data?

Comment: Is just that one table in a different schema, or are all tables accessed via this web2py app in a single schema?

Comment: @Anthony there is only one table. 2 schemas are there currently : `public` and `mychema`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
db.define_table('users',
                Field('first_name'),
                Field('last_name'),
                rname='myschema.users')
```

When making queries, web2py will use the `rname` (in this case, "myschema.users") rather than the `DAL` table name (which is just "users").